# Lost with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a website with various users that all have tables containing their posts.

I'm wanting to create a way for an individual user to pull the posts from just the tables from their friends.

So basically:

```
User A: Post="Hello World!"
User B: Post="Another Post!"

User C: Post="Third!"
```

User D is friends with A and B so when he logs in, this is what I want to be shown:

```
Posts: 
From USER A "Hello World!"
From USER B "Another Post!"
```

I was hoping for a way to make a table that would look to User A and User B for its data, so that in the code all I have to say is

```
SELECT * FROM MyFriendsPosts ORDERBY date_created;
```

and it would show posts from people I'm friends with

I'm pretty new to MySQL so I'm sure there's just something I'm missing

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you define A is a friend of B in database? What is the relation? Clear your database schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rookieB states above, it'd be better to show your Database schema.

Table for posts:

UserId    |    Post

Friendships table

UserId    |    FriendId

Each time a user becomes friends with another user, you create a new row in the Friendships table, thus:

```
  A      |       B
```

Shows that A is friends with B

Or

```
  D      |       A
  D      |       B
```

Shows, in your example, that D is friends with A and B

You can then use a sub query

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.userId IN (SELECT FriendId FROM friendships WHERE UserId='THE_USER_SEARCHING' GROUP BY UserId)
```

OR (I haven't tested either of these... working from memory)

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN friendships ON friendships.userid=posts.userId WHERE users.userId=friendships.friendId
```

Depending on your Database indexing and the number of rows etc, these will have different performance implications and I'd advise testing.

Comment: This looks like it will work, I'll just have to rework some of my tables and code. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_WHERE_YOU_STORE_FRIENDS_AND_POSTS WHERE user_id = ID_OF_USER_A AND user_id = ID_OF_USER_B ORDER BY date_created;
```

But I would recommend you to create 3 tables. One for users, one for user posts and another one for friends.

```
user
user_id | name | login | password

post
post_id | user_id | post_text

friends
user_id | friend_id
```

And read about `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that one reasonable way to structure your DB is:

```
Post(id, text, date_created, uid);//uid === foreign key to table User
User(id, username);
FriendShip(uid1, frid);//both foreign keys to 2 different User
```

Your query could look like:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Post p
WHERE p.uid IN (
    SELECT f.frid
    FROM Friendship f
    WHERE f.uid = YOUR_ID
)
ORDERBY p.date_created;
```

It's not perfect but a good starting point.